# How to set defaultValue for multi select?

Tags: react-select

So, I need to pass defaultValue to a react-select component with enabled multi select. I've tried everything I could think of: array of strings, array of objects, string, etc... Nothing seems to work.

I'm also using the getOptionLabel and getOptionValue, might they be the cause for all this mess?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I would recommend you to read [this guide for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us what you have already tried to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 10):

If you refer to `react-select` documentation, the way to set `defaultValue` to multiple value select:

```
<Select
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[2], colourOptions[3]]}
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={colourOptions}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
/>
```

The structure of `options` is

```
[ 
  {
      label: <string>,
      value: <string>,
    } 
]
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/31j307o3xm?module=/example.js).

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternate way to use **value** as your **defaultValue**.
In my case I have used "id" and "industry" instead of "label" and "value"

```
this.state = {
     interested_industries: [{id:"ANY", industry:"ANY"}]
}
```

And in Select component:-

```
<Select 
    name="interested_industries"
    options={industries}
    value={interested_industries}
    getOptionLabel={ x => x.id}
    getOptionValue={ x => x.industry}
    onChange={this.handleSelect}
    isMulti
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**defaultValue** accepts an object or array of objects.
here an object can be like this :

```
defaultValue = {{ value: 0, label: "John" }}
```

This is also one way:

```
defaultValue = { array1[0] }
```

If you want array of objects for multiple options (isMulti) you can do this:

```
defaultValue = { array1.map(ele => ele) }
```

Where array1 is an array of objects.

```
array1 = [
    { label: "John", value: 0 },
    { label: "Indiana", value: 1 },
    { label: "Stark", value: 2 },
];
```

This solution worked for me. I hope this helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `defaultValue` without index

```
<Select
  defaultValue={existingItems}
  onChange={(option) => onChangeSelect(option)}
  closeMenuOnSelect={false}
  components={animatedComponents}
  isMulti={true}
  options={options}
/>
```

But for this to work you need await loading items from defaultValue if you loading from server
For Example my full code

```
{!kindsByRestaraunt.loading ? (
  <Select
  defaultValue={existingItems}
  onChange={(option) => onChangeSelect(option)}
  closeMenuOnSelect={false}
  components={animatedComponents}
  isMulti={true}
  options={options}
/>
): ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to React documentation, you can do this:

```
    <select multiple={true} value={['B', 'C']}>
```

Where B, C are the default value you want to have selected.